# Python filter Json requests.get result

Tags: python, json

Hi Guys im trying to figure out how to filter the result i get from reading json.

Im using `requests.get` at url https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarket/5662

which returns :

```
{
    "Success": true,
    "Message": null,
    "Data": {
        "TradePairId": 5662,
        "Label": "ETN/BTC",
        "AskPrice": 0.00000493,
        "BidPrice": 0.00000492,
        "Low": 0.00000488,
        "High": 0.00000575,
        "Volume": 12863643.12913574,
        "LastPrice": 0.00000492,
        "BuyVolume": 281607744.12368695,
        "SellVolume": 12716829.67763919,
        "Change": -10.38,
        "Open": 0.00000549,
        "Close": 0.00000492,
        "BaseVolume": 68.58095479,
        "BuyBaseVolume": 86.33526192,
        "SellBaseVolume": 448023579.52566910
    },
    "Error": null
}
```

What I want to do for example is just extract 2 fields.

Lets say "Label" and "AskPrice"

Here is my code:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarket/5662')
json_data = r.json()
```

I need to know what to do from here

I appreciate your help guys :)

Answer (score 2):

The `json` method called on a response returns a python `dict` and so you can access properties by calling `json_data.get(u'Data').get(u'Label')` or `json_data[u'Data'][u'Label']`.

Comment: When i get AskPrice  json_data.get(u'Data').get(u'Label) im wondering how to get the number formatted . Currently its returning 4.79e-06 but what i need is 0.00000479

Comment: The number is still the same in both cases. Probably that the function you use to display it (`print`?) is internally formatting it to make it more human readable.

Answer (score 1):

*this will get you both*

```
json_data['Data']['Label']
json_data['Data']['AskPrice']
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys for your help. i have another question. If i want to also get the "Id" it gives me a key error. do i need to use something other 'Data' ? for the Id Value?

Comment: Also the number returned for AskPrice is 4.79e-06 is there anyway i could get this formatted as it should read 0.00000479

Comment: ignore the id question as its not in the response, just need to know about the AskPrice number